# Azure manage does not show subscritpion

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have an office365 account that I use to access a client's azure subscription.  When I log in to "https://manage.windowsazure.com",  I see the azure subscription that I am looking for.  Problem is that when I try to log in to the same url on a different computer, I do not see this same client's subscription.  Is there something that I need to do on my other computer to be able to manage my client's azure subcription?  The odd thing is that when I used to log in to the "different" computer I would get a message stating that I don't have any subscriptions, so I went through the process of creating a subscription, and not I see the new subscription and still not the client's subscription.

Comment: Click on the Filter icon/menu at the top to choose from your Subscriptions and other accounts. Also ensure you have the right email address and note that an Organisational Account != Microsoft Account.

Comment: I guess I am lost.  I don't see a Filter Icon/menu from my subscriptions.  When I click on "All Items" should I see it there?  Not sure what you mean by Organisational Account != Microsoft Account, but I am using the same account on each computer.